# Inline select selectedIndex

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to use the selectedIndex property inline as opposed to having it in a javascript  tag?

If I had an inline onChange, for example:

```
<select onChange="if(this.value.selectedIndex=='1'){this.value.selectedIndex=='0'}">
```

^this doesn't work but more of an example of what I'm looking for. Is this usage possible?

Comment: So you have your answer already.

Comment: I mean thats just an example, I don;t know if syntax is wrong or maybe I'm calling it incorrectly or even if I'm using it correctly. My question wasn't just to check that one specific line of code. The actual question is whether or not its possible

Comment: First, it's `selectedIndex` and not `selectIndex`. Second, it's a property from the `select` itself, not from its `value`. Third, to assign a value you use a single `=`.   Finally, `selectedIndex` is a number, not a string. `onChange="if (this.selectedIndex == 1) { this.selectedIndex = 0; }"` Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t4Bas/

Comment: Yes, it works. Try and select 3 http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8Hjvn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it works - some sample html:

```
<select onchange="alert('selected: ' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value="option 1">1</option>
    <option value="option 2">2</option>
    <option value="option 3">3</option>
</select>
```

This will display the value of the selected option.

```
this.selectedIndex
```

gets the selectedIndex

```
this.options[...].value
```

gets the actual option value (together with the selectedIndex)

To get your example to work you'd need to change it to:

```
<select onchange="if(this.selectedIndex == 1){this.selectedIndex = 0}">
    <option value="option 1">1</option>
    <option value="option 2">2</option>
    <option value="option 3">3</option>
</select>
```

If you select number 2 it will reset to number 1 (because it's a zero-based index) while selecting 3 or 1 will have no effect

Comment: `this.value` is enough to get the selected value.